# framelayout is not working

Tags: android, android-framelayout

am creating an application in which i am using framelayout .....
I have used three class
1) activity
2)selecting image 
3)drawing on image

so my activity class is as follow

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         i= new FirstImage(this);


         j=(Draw)findViewById(R.id.info);
         t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
         k=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         back=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.drawable.monotone_arrow_next_left);
         next=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.drawable.monotone_arrow_next_lrightcopy);
         if (count==0){
             ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.human);

         }
         addListenerOnButton();
    }
    private void addListenerOnButton() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub




        next.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(count==0){

                    //i.startAnimation(animationFadeout);
                    ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.hand);
                back.setEnabled(true);
                count++;

                addListenerOnButton();

                }
                else if (count==1){
                    //i.startAnimation(animationFadeout);
                    ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.tissue);
                    count++;

                    addListenerOnButton();

                }

                else if (count==2){
                    //i.startAnimation(animationFadeout);
                    ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.cell);
                    count++;

                    addListenerOnButton();


                }
                else if (count==3){
                    //nucleus
                    //i.startAnimation(animationFadeout);
                    ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.nucleus);
                    count++;

                    addListenerOnButton();

                }
                else if (count==4){
                    //nchromosome
                    //i.startAnimation(animationFadeout);
                    ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.chromosome);
                    count++;

                    addListenerOnButton();

                }
                else
                {   //double helix
                    //i.startAnimation(animationFadeout);
                    count++;
                    ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.dnahelix);
                    next.setEnabled(false);

                    addListenerOnButton();

                }

            }
        });

        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(count==1){
                    //i.startAnimation(animationFadeout);
                    ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.human);
                    back.setEnabled(false);
                    count--;

                    addListenerOnButton();

                    }
                    else if (count==2){
                        //i.startAnimation(animationFadeout);
                        ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.hand);
                        count--;

                        addListenerOnButton();

                    }

                    else if (count==3){
                        //i.startAnimation(animationFadeout);
                        ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.tissue);
                        count--;

                        addListenerOnButton();


                    }
                    else if (count==4){
                        //i.startAnimation(animationFadeout);
                        ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.cell);
                        count--;

                        addListenerOnButton();

                    }
                    else if (count==5){
                        //nucleus
                        //i.startAnimation(animationFadeout);
                        ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.nucleus);
                        count--;

                        addListenerOnButton();


                    }
                    else {
                        //chromosome
                        //count==6
                        //i.startAnimation(animationFadeout);
                        ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.chromosome);
                        count--;

                        addListenerOnButton();
                        next.setEnabled(true);

                    }
                }
            });
    }


}
```

my class which is selecting an image it is as follow ..

```
   public class FirstImage extends ImageView implements OnTouchListener {

    ImageView i;
    MotionEvent event;
    int x;
    Bitmap image;
    String huma ="human";
    String info = "";
     float y = 0; //init value 
     float z = 0; //init value
     Animation animationFadeIn;
    Draw child;

    public FirstImage(Context context) { 
        super(context); 
        child=new Draw (context);
        i= new ImageView (context); 


        } 
    public FirstImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { 
        super(context, attrs);
        } 


    public void changeImage(int id){
        final Animation animationFadeout=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.zoomout);
                    i.setImageResource(id);
                    i.startAnimation(animationFadeout);
                    i.setOnTouchListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
    }
```

my class which will draw on the image it is as follow

```
public class Draw extends View {
    String info = "";
    float x = 0;    
    float y = 0;    
    int color = Color.GREEN;    
    public Draw(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Draw(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
          super(context, attrs);

    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setTextSize(30);

        canvas.drawLine(x-10, y, x+10, y, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(x, y-10, x, y+10, paint);
        canvas.drawText(info, x, y, paint);

    }

    public void updateInfo(String t_info, float t_x, float t_y){
        info = t_info;
        x = t_x;
        y = t_y;

        invalidate();
    }

    public void clearInfo(){
        info = "";
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

it is showing unexpeteced closing of application ...but in the logcat showing

```
   05-21 15:55:18.964: E/AndroidRuntime(850): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 15:55:18.964: E/AndroidRuntime(850): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nam/com.example.nam.AshActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 15:55:18.964: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
05-21 15:55:18.964: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
05-21 15:55:18.964: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-21 15:55:18.964: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
05-21 15:55:18.964: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-21 15:55:18.964: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-21 15:55:18.964: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
05-21 15:55:18.964: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 15:55:18.964: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-21 15:55:18.964: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-21 15:55:18.964: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-21 15:55:18.964: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-21 15:55:18.964: E/AndroidRuntime(850): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 15:55:18.964: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at com.example.nam.AshActivity.addListenerOnButton(AshActivity.java:48)
05-21 15:55:18.964: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at com.example.nam.AshActivity.onCreate(AshActivity.java:40)
05-21 15:55:18.964: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-21 15:55:18.964: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
05-21 15:55:18.964: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  ... 11 more
```

my xml file is as follow ....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >


  <!--  Screen Design for VIDEOS -->
<TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/tablelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

     <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

          <TextView
               android:id="@+id/textView"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="15dip"
              android:text="pic on click which will tell where is the dna located in human body or cell "
              android:textSize="18dip" />
      </TableRow>


      <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
         <com.example.nam.FirstImage
             android:id="@+id/image"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
          <com.example.nam.Draw
             android:id="@+id/info"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

      </FrameLayout>   
      </TableRow>

      <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

              <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/button1"
                  android:layout_width="100dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:src="@drawable/monotone_arrow_next_left"/>
              <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/button2"
                  android:layout_width="100dp"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:src="@drawable/monotone_arrow_next_lrightcopy"/>

          </LinearLayout>

      </TableRow>
       <TableRow
          android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="15dip"
              android:text="please don't mind  "
              android:textSize="18dip" />
          </TableRow>

  </TableLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "FrameLayout" not working? How does your layout look like? If you have a force close, the logcat does show an error, you just have to look for it (maybe filtering by package name).

Comment: @rekaszeru but it is not showing that error thats why i am too much surprised....

Comment: See this line : `Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class com.example.nam.FirstImage`. It's saying that your error is in your xml file, so probably you didn't include it with the right name.Check your xml file and if you can't fix it just paste it here.

Comment: @i have edited my question one more time ......

Comment: Thanks! please see the answer, and try including that namespace declaration into your layout's root element. Let us know if it works.

Comment: Show us what you have on line 40 in `FirstImage` class.

Comment: i.setImageResource(id); is the line no 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error points to a row when you are using a custom view: `com.example.nam.FirstImage`.

When using your own `View` extensions in an xml layout, you should declare a namespace to them.

What you are missing is a line:

```
xmlns:name="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.nam"
```

so your layout's root element should look like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:nam="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.nam" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

**Edit1**: Now the `NullPointerException` is inside your `FirstImage` class.

There you have a variable named `event` of type `MotionEvent`, which is nowhere initialized, but you use it inside your `changeImage` method:

```
i.onTouchEvent(event);
```

This must throw the `NPE`. Since you call that method from `onCreate`, you cannot assign to it a valid `MotionEvent`, this way you need either

- to make up one, or
- check if the `event` member is null, and only call the `onTouchEvent` if it is not null!

**Eidt2**: ...after comments / chat, here is what you should do:

- remove the `i.onTouchEvent(event);` from your `changeImage` method;
- implement properly the `onTouch` method to show the desired text.
- remove the `ImageView` instance, and use `this` instead.

This way your `FirstImage` class should change:

```
public class FirstImage extends ImageView implements OnTouchListener
{
    MotionEvent event;
    int x;
    Bitmap image;
    String huma = "human";
    String info = "";
    float y = 0; // init value
    float z = 0; // init value
    Animation animationFadeIn;
    Draw child;

    public FirstImage(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        child = new Draw(context);
    }

    public FirstImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void changeImage(int id)
    {
        final Animation animationFadeout = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                getContext(), R.anim.zoomout);
        this.setImageResource(id);
        this.startAnimation(animationFadeout);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1)
    {
    //  TODO: Here you show the text you want, e.g.:
    //  final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
    //  tv.setText("This image is about...");
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Edit3**: If you would simplify / clarify a bit your `addClickListener` method, that would be nice too.

You really don't need to add the listeners to those buttons over and over again...

```
private void addListenerOnButton()
{
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            switch (count)
            {
                case 0:
                    ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.hand);
                    back.setEnabled(true);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.tissue);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.cell);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.nucleus);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.chromosome);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.dnahelix);
                    next.setEnabled(false);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            count++;
        }
    });

    back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            switch (count)
            {
                case 1:
                    ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.human);
                    back.setEnabled(false);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.hand);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.tissue);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.cell);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.nucleus);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.chromosome);
                    next.setEnabled(true);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            count--;
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit4**: Also, please correct your layout xml file, and instead of having `ImageViews` declared for `button1` and `button2`, use `ImageButtons` as you try to cast them in the `onCreate` method anyway:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/monotone_arrow_next_left"/>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/monotone_arrow_next_lrightcopy"/>
```

and the assignment is done by the button's `@id` attribute, not by the drawable you have on them!

```
back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

Comment: it is also showing me error but they are now less iam edited my qoustion

Comment: What is your application package? I assumed it is `com.example.nam`, since that's what your `FirstImage` is declared in. In case it is just `com.example`, you must point the namespace towards that package: `xmlns:nam="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example"`. What is `com.example.namespace.AdsActivity`? I mean `com.example.namespace`: is it a typo?

Comment: `onTouchEvent` should be called when a touch event actually occurs (not manually, but through a listener, so your listener must be enough). Why do you want to call that method anyway? I don't see it's implementation.

Comment: basically i am using firstImage class for changing the n no of image and implementing the ontouch event on that

Comment: ok, but why are you calling that `onTouchEvent` on the image, instead of registering a listener to it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11506/discussion-between-rekaszeru-and-ashishsingh)

Answer (score 1):

Check this from official documentation about FrameLayout :

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity attribute.

If I was you I would try to use two different `FrameLayouts` to see if it will work..but as I can see from your stacktrace the problem is in your xml file.

**EDIT :**

So here is the code which is working. Put this on your Activity :

```
public class AshActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
ImageView i;
Draw j;
TextView t,k;
ImageView back;
ImageView next;
int count=0;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     i= new FirstImage(this);
     if (count==0)
         ((FirstImage) i).changeImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
     j=(Draw)findViewById(R.id.info);
     t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
     k=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     back=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     next=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.button2);
     addListenerOnButton();

} }
```

And that should do the trick! : )

Comment: i.setImageResource(id); is the line no 40

Comment: On that line you have two options which can cause that exception..your imageView is null or the resource which you are trying to set on it.

Comment: So here is your problem..In your constructor in FirstImage, you are creating it with giving a Context as parameter, but in your Activity you are trying to create it as imageView without creating any instance to it. So that's why your ImageView in null. You need to create it first as you write it's constructor in your class and than set an image to it.

Comment: my image view is initialized as follow  i= new ImageView (context); and i am passing the resource id from the R.java class file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11502/discussion-between-android-droid-and-ashishsingh)